# Can I drive my friend's car without having car insurance myself?

Tags: united-states, california, liability, vehicle, insurance

I haven't owned a car for months, and I'm about to go on a road trip with a few friends. We want to split the driving between ourselves, but I haven't owned a car in months, so I no longer pay for auto insurance.

Can I legally drive my friend's car? Whose insurance applies in the case of an accident?

Comment: Get your friend to call their insurance company and read the policy.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a general rule as to whether the owner's insurance covers your liability – that's a "check the policy" issue. You are required to have liability insurance and to provide proofs of such insurance.

Comment: You may also be able to buy "spot" insurance for just this outing, similar to what car rental companies offer (but hopefully, more reasonably priced).  Try calling your previous insurance agent and asking them about this.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'm not aware of any U.S. state that requires</strike> Many U.S. states do not require personal vehicle *drivers* to be insured.  I.e., with the exception of some commercial classes of vehicles, the law only requires that *cars* driven on public roads be insured (to levels specified by law or regulation).

In every case I have encountered, state insurance regulators do allow insurers to assess premiums based on the owners and drivers of insured cars.  Therefore, **you must review the insurance policy to ensure that your use of the car complies with its terms**.  [Policies will usually have exceptions or guidelines for when "occasional, casual, or intermittent" drivers must be declared](https://insurance.freeadvice.com/information/auto/article/199).

If an undeclared driver has an accident, and the insurer determines the driver should have been declared, then the insurer might cancel its coverage or increase the premiums charged to the owner.  Both the driver and the owner could even find themselves without insurance coverage for the incident.

Comment: Although, RCW 46.30.020 "No person may operate a motor vehicle subject to registration ...unless the person is insured under a motor vehicle liability policy", so both the operator and vehicle are bound by law.

Comment: @user6726 - Hmm... I'm not familiar with WA, but it's not known as the biggest outlier in insurance regulation.  Do you happen to know whether the *effect* of that law is the same as if it only stipulated vehicle insurance because (I conjecture) nobody can write auto insurance in WA that *doesn't* cover "occasional" drivers of a car?

Comment: ORC 4509.101 is about operating (or permitting). I'll see if I can find out if there's such an effect.

Comment: @user6726: I would most likely expect to find it in the rules or conventions on auto policies that are approved for sale by the WA insurance regulator.  I have not often been able to find those sorts of rules, perhaps because they aren't always codified.  Though I know better than to bet against your ability to find anything!

Comment: They must offer, you may decline. http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=284-20-300 (2). If you reject the required liability insurance, you are supposed to have comparable cash on hand or functional equivalent per RCW 46.30.020. As I recall, Ohio is the same.

Comment: @user6726: So what's it like to be pulled over in WA in someone else's car?  Do police demand "license, insurance, and registration," and then when they see the licensee isn't the insured do they come back and say, "OK, sir, now show us *your* insurance?"